# [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'boatType' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database

```
INSERT INTO BOAT(VID, name, yearBuilt, boatType, numBeds, TEUs)
            VALUE (10, 'John', '1988-02-05', 'YACHT', 24, NULL);

CREATE TABLE BOAT (
    VID         INT NOT NULL,
    name        varchar(20),
    yearBuilt   DATE,
    boatType    ENUM ('YACHT', 'CARGO SHIP', 'NULL'),
    numBeds     INT,
    TUEs        INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (VID)
);
```

Comment: TEUs is not TUEs !

Comment: I fixed it, but still get the same error!

Comment: this isn't the order of execution right.. the table exists before the insert...  I'd assume you'd get an unknown table boat otherwise...  unless boat already exists w/o boatType in the database and it's erroring on the insert so the create's not executed...  that create is the DDL of table BOAT which has already been executed right?

Comment: The table BOAT already exist. My bad, I put it in that order only here.